# Include precompiled header in ifdef

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompile

I have a cross-platform project and thing is on Windows I want to use precompiled headers(its really vital in this case) and Linux I dont want it. So I would like to have something like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "precompiled.h"
#endif //#ifdef WIN32
```

When I build on Windows I get this annoying error, claiming:

```
PCH warning: header stop cannot be in a macro or #if block. An intellisense pch was not generated
```

Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

Thanks on advance.

Comment: not sure but it seems as if it is a warning, not an error

Comment: Why do you want it on Windows (it's "really vital") but not on Linux? Weird.

Comment: Its  a bit long story, but thing is that I really need this precompiled header be included in Windows build, but not used in Linux.

Comment: Just move the #ifdef into the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

I already have this problem and for me one of these two options worked for me.

1) Maybe if you add `#pragma once` at the start of the file (even before the #ifndef _WIN32 header guard).

2) Or you can add on your header files this skecth:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H
... contents of myheader.h
#endif /* MYHEADER_H */
```

This will guarantee your header will be compiled just once and this warning will disapear (at least for me).

Hope it works!

Comment: You miss the point. `#ifdef _WIN32` is in cpp file (to conditionally include pch).